# How to get table columns using a foreign key in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

so I have these tables:

a: id (primary key, foreign key to b), details, steps

b: id(primary key), field1, field2, field3, field4

How do I get all of the data of a and b using a select statement? would a "select * from a" automatically get all of the details of b associated with a? What would that specifically do?

Comment: which server type do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Change the join type (e.g. to LEFT OUTER JOIN, RIGHT OUTER JOIN, or FULL OUTER JOIN) if you want to include rows that don't have a match in the other table.